# How to detect date time from the SIM card?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing offline app using **Cordova** and i need to get the time from the SIM card and i searched for plugins that can get the time from the SIM card

any solution or idea like a new way to get the time from offline mode will be appreciated

Comment: Not possible from my point of view. Would love to see if there is any

Comment: Why the time from the SIM card? What do you do if there is no SIM card is inserted?

Comment: if i reached for a way to get the time from the sim card , i will make a restriction for the users of the application to use it with SIM card only !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this issue by making a background service that can validate the time and if the user changed the time in offline mode then he should go online

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin, maybe it helps:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sim

Comment: thanks for your reply , i checked this plugin but it don't return the time from the sim card

Comment: I know, but you wrote above, that you would like to check if datetime from sim exist, to restrict your app. With this plugin you have ways to check if a sim card is available.

Comment: thanks , i will check first if the device have SIM card .. can you help me how to retrieve the date time from the SIM card ?